# Centering Activity Indicator view on its layer

Tags: ios, objective-c, calayer, centering, uiactivityindicatorview

I have not been able to solve this problem searching on the net. I have an Activity indicator view with a layer I would like to customize. More specifically I want to increase its size. The problem is that the activity indicator is not centered anymore on its background.

It should be something rather simple but I cannot figure out how to do it. Managing the layer seems more concise than adding an other subview.

Here is what I get with the code below.

[image: background layer is centered but not the activity indicator]

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *activityView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]
                                             initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    [activityView setColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    activityView.layer.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width/2-30, self.view.bounds.size.height/2-30, 60, 60);
    activityView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
    [activityView.layer setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor colorWithRed:2/255.0 green:79/255.0 blue:105/255.0 alpha:0.9] CGColor]];

    activityView.center = self.view.center;
    //activityView.center = also tried to center on layer, layer.contentsRect,... without any success;
    [activityView startAnimating];
    [self.view addSubview:activityView];
```

If anyone could help me...

Comment: I recommend this awesome library https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD.
So easy to implement, it will save your life.

Comment: Thanks I will have a look!

Comment: EDIT: It's perfect!!

Comment: Glad it helped. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to centering activity:

```
activityView.subviews[0].center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(activityView.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(activityView.bounds));
```

But I think it's bad way. Try to make view and add Activity to this view without change its frame.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the activity indicator larger try using this

```
activityView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.75, 1.75);
```

and don't forget to add `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`

So your code should look like this:

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *activityView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]
                                             initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    [activityView setColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    activityView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
    [activityView.layer setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor colorWithRed:2/255.0 green:79/255.0 blue:105/255.0 alpha:0.9] CGColor]];

    activityView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.75, 1.75);

    activityView.center = self.view.center;
    [activityView startAnimating];
    [self.view addSubview:activityView];
```

I hope it helps

Comment: In fact I just want the "background" to be enlarged without modifiying the indicator view itself... But thanks anyway!